# Are other human spirits reincarnated in the world of Avatar: The Last Airbender?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender, the-legend-of-korra

Obviously, human spirits can reincarnate, as the Avatar is constantly reincarnated into another body.

Through *Avatar: The Last Airbender* and *Avatar: The Legend of Korra*, we see and hear about spirits of people which are trapped in the spirit world. Do any human spirits *other than* the Avatar ever get reincarnated into a new body?

Answer (score 17):

There seems to be very little specific information regarding this, in the canon.

However, there is one clue which makes me think that all humans do have multiple lifetimes: when Raava is speaking to Wan as he lays dying on the battlefield, she tells him "we will be together for all of your lifetimes."

[image]

It's a subtle thing, and definitely open to interpretation, but my reading of that line (the text and the delivery) is that "all of your lifetimes" isn't a surprising concept.  Wan doesn't react with surprise to the thought of being reincarnated, and Raava just throws it out there with no preamble.  It isn't "Don't worry, I will allow you to live again" or "Yours is a story that will cross many lifetimes."  The multiple lifetimes bit is just assumed, the important thing is that they will be together through all of them.

It's hardly conclusive, but given that bit of evidence I'd say the scales are tipped toward all people having multiple lifetimes in the Avatar universe.

Comment: Maybe another subtle hint is uncle Iroh (and a few other ghosts lost in the fog) since we don't see the spritual world crowded with ghosts we can assume they return to the material world as incarnations.

Comment: @jean: I don't think those examples are evidence of normal people reincarnating. Iroh *chose* to leave his physical body behind and inhabit the spirit world. On the other hand, the people in the Fog of Lost Souls are effectively prisoners.

Answer (score 0):

There is no certain knowledge about it, according to the first series to last one (korra).

But this is seems how is it works;
Actually there is no reincarnation, there are just some sprits, and when a human's sprit bounded with a sprit from sprits world, actually the one from the sprit world caryying the knowledge and experiences and making a bridge/connection between these sprits and just passes to other nation.

You see when the bridge collapsed(unbounding raava from korra's sprit and destruction of her), all connection to past lives disappeared.

Based on uncle iroh, we may say when you die, your sprit is going back to sprit world or the other explanation when you were in sprit world if your body dies, you stuck in the sprit world. Like aiwei or commander zhao.

As conclusion, seems there is no sign of reincarnation. This is just assumed as reincarnation.

Answer (score -1):

In ATLA, the Avatar was a proper or standard reincarnation, past lives of the same human spirit. Very Buddhist in nature. The air nomads were proper monks and strived for oneness, moving beyond the reincarnation cycle into nirvana. When the previous Air Avatar told Aang that this is impossible for air avatars, he got mad. Denied nirvana and all.

Then the fire nation, er, I mean LOK came around and changed this. It is no longer a person spirit reincarnating. The addition of Raava being the never dying spirit of the Avatar, makes the human spirits less likely to be reincarnations. They are bound by Raava like dogs on a leash. Raava never dies, and as such doesn't reincarnate. No other spirits are shown to reincarnate. In fact Vatu infested spirits are shown to be killed and referred to as dying, not moving on.

Answer (score -2):

Though it has never been confirmed, it is believed that Momo, Aang's Flying Lemur is the reincarnation of Monk Gyatso, the father figure to Aang. You can see Momo's humorous personality, and his relationship to Aang. It would be fitting for Monk Gyatso to reincarnate into Momo because he probably wanted to see Aang again. Monk Gyatso was killed in the Air Nomad Genocide, and in the Southern Air Temple, he guided Aang to Monk Gyatso's skeleton. It is likely that Monk Gyatso would be Momo.

Comment: Could you [edit] this to give a bit more evidence to back this theory up? It seems like a good one but the answer as it stands at the moment is a bit lackluster in my opinion.

Answer (score -3):

I think that the Avatar series follows the idea of reincarnation. As stated above, I feel there are slight references to it being true with nobody really stating it outright. I have a personal head canon that follows the idea. Basically, all "mortal" creatures were once part of the spirit world before separating off and becoming mortal by taking physical forms. They essentially either reincarnate, or are travel to the spirit world after enlightenment. While there is no solid evidence to back that theory up, there was a quote in the video game claiming that everything was one, which implies that both the material and the spirit world are part of the same universe. I like to think of it like spirited away personally.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE. Answers here should be restricted to canon (unless otherwise stated in the question). Commentary about "personal head canon" should be reserved for comments. Once you have earned 50 reputation you will be able to comment everywhere.